# Store two child records for a resource - ActiveRecord | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 project that has `Teacher`, `Student`, and `EmergencyContact` models. I'd like to store two `EmergencyContact` records for each `Teacher` and `Student` record. Given that both the `Teacher` and `Student` models will share the same requirement for `EmergencyContact` records, I though it'd be most efficient to have the two models share the same `EmergencyContact` table.

Is this the best way to go? What would be the best way to set this up with ActiveRecord?

The below ERD shows the concept:

[image]
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for this type of requirement it is done making use of **Polymorphic association** in **ActiveRecord**. You can find more information about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

The setup for this would be something similar as mentioned below :

**In models**

```
# In app/models/emergency_contact.rb
class EmergencyContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :emergency_contactable, polymorphic :true
end

# In app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :emergency_contacts, as: :emergency_contactable
end

# In app/models/student.rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :emergency_contacts, as: :emergency_contactable
end
```

**Schema migrations (new fields in emergency contacts table) required**

```
class AddEmergyContactable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :emergency_contacts, :emergency_contactable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

Let me know if this helps.